# admob interstitial ad shows after minute it should

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, interstitial, ads

I'm making a 2D game in Unity3D. When a main character dies, a menu with "restart" ( which is Application.LoadLevel("thisLevel")) and "go to main menu" options appears. But I need interstitial ad to appear before menu (Character dies => ad appears). I did it. But here is the problem: Character dies, interstitial ad appears, I close it, press restart button in menu, I make character die again, and ad appear just after 1-2 minutes, which is strange. Then I press restart and make character die again, it appears instantly, as it should be. But if I don't wait for ad after second "death" ad does not appear after third "death" and so on. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class AdBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

private const string INTERSTITIAL_ID = "ca-app-pub-myNumers";

public InterstitialAd interstitial;

private bool showed;

void Start () {
    DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
    showed = false;

    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(INTERSTITIAL_ID);
    AdRequest request2 = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    interstitial.LoadAd(request2);
}

void Update () {

}
public void showAd () {
    if (interstitial.IsLoaded() && !showed) {
        interstitial.Show();
        showed = true;
    }
}
public void destroyAd () {
    interstitial.Destroy();
}
}
```

I call functions from this script when character dies. Here is my manifest file if you need:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"         android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="com.example.admobtest" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
 <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <!-- Google Mobile Ads Permissions -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
<!-- meta-data tag for Google Play services -->
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
  <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigaton|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
</activity>
<!-- Google Mobile Ads Activity -->
  <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigati         on|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
  </activity>
 </application>
 <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
 </manifest>
```

What is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding the ad instead of destroying it

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't find anything like interstitial.Hide() in admob documentation. How can I hide it?

Comment: hmm.. when is destroy ad called? try removing it without the hide option if you don't have it

Comment: Destroy ad is called right before Application.LoadLevel("thisLevel"). Click on "restart button" => Destroy ad, Application.LoadLevel("thisLevel"). What do you mean removing it without hide option?

Comment: My bad, i formulated that incorrectly. You are calling DontDestroyOnLoad on your gameObject that contains the script AdBehaviourScript . In the function destroyAd () you are destroying your ad and hence on the second call you don't have anything to show. Don't destroy the ad until you are sure you will reload it or won't use it

Comment: A new Ad is generating in a start() function of Ad gameObject. So, it's generating after every level reload. And when user clicks on "restart button" it executes two lines of code: 1) Destroy ad 2) Application.LoadLevel, so destroyng ad is 100% percent before restarting.

Comment: i've just checked this. If you add DontDestroyOnLoad on a gameObject and load another level the Start() function of that gameObject is not called again. Please check this with a Debug in Start(). If you load the same level again, than you will have multiple instances of the same gameobject.

Comment: I've just tried to do it without destroying ad and without DontDestroyOnLoad. It's working the same: second time ad is showing after 30-40 seconds it should.

Comment: Try leaving the DontDestroyOnLoad just remove interstitial.Destroy(); and add showed = false in your destroyAd () function . When you removed the DontDestroyOnLoad from your gameObject it sends a new load request in every start and it takes a while for the ad to load. You can't control that time.

Comment: I've tried it too, does not work. There are enough time from start() to a moment main character dies to load interstitial ad. First time ad is showing instantly, second time it shows after half minute.

Comment: Maybe I should play with OnAwake() function in Ad script?

Answer (score 0):

You should check isInterstitialReady before displaying the ad.
Actually what happens is that when an ad is displayed then the admob plugin start downloading new ad. due to which when you call the ad the second time it is not yet downloaded and displays after a sec. You should check if your ad is ready then dislpay your ad.